# SQL Query results into dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the names of the events from a table in a database, i need to insert this data in a dropdown list, so then someone clicks them and then the information for this specific event displays...

Here is my code up to now..

```
<?php

require "config.php"; // Your Database details 
?>

<?PHP


$SQL = "SELECT title_en_US FROM civicrm_event";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
// Write out our query.
$query = "SELECT title_en_US FROM civicrm_event";
// Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
print $db_field['title_en_US'] . "<BR>";

}

?>
```

Can you tell me how to put first the event names into a dropdown list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code

```
$options='';
while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $options .= "<option>".$db_field['title_en_US']."</option>";
}
```

For the html part,

```
<select name="titles"><? echo $options; ?></select>
```

Comment: Hey thanks...

This is the code i generated, the dropdown works fine but it seems to be empty... the rows are printed but not the names inside..
<?PHP

$SQL = "SELECT title_en_US FROM civicrm_event";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
// Write out our query.
$query = "SELECT title_en_US FROM civicrm_event";
// Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

$options='';
while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $options .= "<option>".$row['title_en_US']."</option>";
} 
?>



<select name="titles"><? echo $options; ?></select>

Comment: please use the updated code. Use $db_field['title_en_US'] instead of $row['title_en_US']

Comment: Thanks :)
It worked like a charm :)
Can you please give me a hint on how i should do now... i mean once i select an option i need to extract information from this option... let me explain myself

I select an event name which is "Computer Science Party"

Then i need to extract information like location,time, date for this event... i should give a method to the form...or something?

Comment: I created this form: 

    <form action="" method="get" name="report">
    <select name="titles"><? echo $options; ?></select>
    </form>
How can i extract data for each event i select?

Thanks..

Comment: since you are using get method, you can access the value from the titles as $_GET['titles']. So this would give you the event selected.I hope this answers your question.If so, please mark the answer.

Comment: So, i got something like this:
<form action="" method="$_GET['titles']" name="report">
<select name="titles"><? echo $options; ?></select>
</form>
But from there, how am i supposed to retrieve data for the specific event?... Do i have to do any other php document or something?
I need just the idea not the code please :)
You've helped me enough and it's not my intention to ask someone to write me a code... :)

Comment: No not like what you mentioned.It would be better if you go through the documents in http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp. What i tried to mention is that once the form is submitted, you can access the values from the dropdown as $_GET['titles'] , and can build a query based on that

Comment: I have this last question please

This is the form: <form action="event_information.php" method="get" name="report">
<select name="titles"><? echo $options; ?></select>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

and this si what event_information holds: Welcome <?php echo $_GET["titles"]; ?>.<br />

When querying for the information of this event i'v selected, ow am i going to start it?

Does the event_information.php know which information to retrieve..?

Comment: in the event_information.php, you can use sql query like "select * from civicrm_event where title_en_US=".addslashes($_GET['titles']). and get the info. I would suggest you to go through the docs in w3schools.com , which has some simple example for you to understand.

Comment: Yes, i got it, thanks for the information :)
You were very very helpful :), i'm going to check through w3schools.com
Thanks again!
Have a good day!

Comment: Hey...sorry for disturbing again...
I'm having this issue... i put the code to retrieve the data and i get an error..

$SQL = "SELECT created_date FROM civicrm_event WHERE  title_en_US="'.addslashes($_GET['titles']).'"";